# Multilingual website with different content and look

Tags: multi-language

I want to make the second language for a site. But actually, I don't need to translate the current content. That is why I think it is not effective to use plugins like Polylang.

I was thinking about just adding new pages with its own template files, different menu, flags would be just as links to front pages.

Is this approach alright?

Comment: It’s a matter of opinion, but if you want the content structures and looks to be different, then yes you’ll effectively be running two separate sites.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook I haven't been talking about two separate sites but just one - creating the second language by adding pages wrote in a different language with its own template php file. Or are you suggesting adding another wp installation?

Comment: One drawback I see with creating separate templates would be extra work keeping track of changes. If the page template is updated, then you would need to update the other language's template as well. Do you need to create a different template file, i.e. can you use the same template file and write content in the other language? Unless you have content that is hard-coded into the template, you should be able to use the same template and replace the content in the other language.

Comment: @cseto Main language has too much of different content, the second language will have just a little info about organization, it needs a different layout. That extra work is a must indeed.

Comment: The reason why I am asking is that I have never seen it done this way. To me this looks like the least work.